# Cannot start old XAMPP after reinstall Windows

Tags: windows, mysql, port, xampp, software-conflict

I have XAMPP located at D:\XAMPP. After reinstall Windows, I can't start that XAMPP anymore, in the XAMPP control panel, I quit Skype, changed its port to not use 443/80 port too, but it's not work. There are no other apache/mysql process. I have a database in that Xampp, how can't I start it, or is there anyway to retrieve that database without start that XAMPP?

The Event Viewer content

```
   Can't create test file E:\xampp\mysql\data\LEADER.lower-test
```

Comment: Did any drive letters change when you reinstalled Windows? You could also check your XAMP config files for any references to `e:\`. Also check any XAMP registry entries.

Comment: Yes. Change drive letter is a good point. Before reinstall Windows, its name is E:\XAMPP. I change drive letter back to E, and Apache service now can start, but MySQL service still unable to start

Comment: Look in the error logs for MySQL. I use wamp but I guess xampp is similar. `xampp\logs`?